# SQL Server : Insert blank line in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may be so last year but I'm using SQL Server 2005

```
stmpdate      intime
----------------------
2014-10-08   08:04:43
2014-10-09   07:57:13
2014-10-10   07:57:14
2014-10-16   07:79:56
2014-10-17   07:45:56
```

I have this table. It keeps check-in time of the employee, but this employee didn't check-in everyday in the month. So what I want it to be is something like this

```
    stmpdate    intime
1   2014-10-01  
2   2014-10-02  
3   2014-10-03  
4   2014-10-04  
5   2014-10-05  
6   2014-10-06  
7   2014-10-07  
8   2014-10-08  08:04:43
9   2014-10-09  07:57:13
10  2014-10-10  07:57:14
11  2014-10-11  
12  2014-10-12  
13  2014-10-13  
14  2014-10-14  
15  2014-10-15  
16  2014-10-16  07:59:56
17  2014-10-17  07:45:56
18  2014-10-18  
19  2014-10-19  
20  2014-10-20  
21  2014-10-21  
22  2014-10-22  
23  2014-10-23  
24  2014-10-24  
25  2014-10-25  
26  2014-10-26  
27  2014-10-27  
28  2014-10-28  
29  2014-10-29  
30  2014-10-30  
31  2014-10-31
```

I tried to make a temp table which contains every date in the month, and then left join it with the first table I mentioned, but it seemed to not work.

```
declare @datetemp table (
stmpdate varchar(10)
);
insert into @datetemp 
SELECT '2014-10-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-10-02'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-10-03'
....
```

and

```
SELECT dtt.stmpdate, intime
FROM @datetemp dtt left join v_dayTimesheet
on dtt.stmpdate=v_dayTimesheet.stmpdate
WHERE (emp_no = '001234567')
```

here is the result of query above

```
stmpdate    intime
2014-10-08  08:04:43
2014-10-09  07:57:13
2014-10-10  07:57:14
2014-10-16  07:59:56
2014-10-17  07:45:56
```

and here is the result of select * from @datetemp

```
2014-10-01
2014-10-02
2014-10-03
2014-10-04
2014-10-05
2014-10-06
2014-10-07
2014-10-08
2014-10-09
2014-10-10
2014-10-11
2014-10-12
2014-10-13
2014-10-14
2014-10-15
2014-10-16
2014-10-17
2014-10-18
2014-10-19
2014-10-20
2014-10-21
2014-10-22
2014-10-23
2014-10-24
2014-10-25
2014-10-26
2014-10-27
2014-10-28
2014-10-29
2014-10-30
2014-10-31
```

Comment: your where is the problem.  it needs to be = ID or is null for the left outer join you're using.

Comment: You could also write `left join v_dayTimesheet on dtt.stmpdate=v_dayTimesheet.stmpdate and emp_no = '001234567'` - with condition as another join clause instead of `WHERE`

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2003** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and now 2014. So which one are you really using??

Answer (score 1):

you're filtering for only where `emp_no` has a value.  if they didn't check in, it won't return on that row because you just have date info and no employee number.  so you have to allow for equal or null.

```
SELECT  dtt.stmpdate, intime

FROM    @datetemp dtt 

        left outer join v_dayTimesheet
           on dtt.stmpdate=v_dayTimesheet.stmpdate

WHERE   emp_no = '001234567' or emp_no is null
```

also, for your dates... check this out: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/03/generate-start-and-end-date-range-using.html

```
DECLARE
@StartDate datetime = '2010-01-01',
@EndDate   datetime = '2010-03-01'

;WITH datetemp as
(
       SELECT @StartDate as stmpdate
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, stmpdate)
       FROM   datetemp 
       WHERE  DATEADD(day, 1, stmpdate) <= @EndDate    
)

SELECT stmpdate   
FROM   datetemp;
```

you would then select from `datetemp` as a normal table.  beware, though, a common table expression can only be used once and immediately following the `with` statement.

---

just trust me on this one... run this query and see how your blank lines occur:

```
SELECT  dtt.stmpdate, intime, emp_no 

FROM    @datetemp dtt 

        left outer join v_dayTimesheet
           on dtt.stmpdate=v_dayTimesheet.stmpdate

WHERE   emp_no = '001234567' or emp_no is null
```

all these lines will return with emp_no = 001234567

```
stmpdate    intime
2014-10-08  08:04:43
2014-10-09  07:57:13
2014-10-10  07:57:14
2014-10-16  07:59:56
2014-10-17  07:45:56
```

and all your blank lines will have null as emp_no.

Comment: Oh!! thanks, I got what my problem is.. but the another problem is I have many emp_no in the table. There won't be null for emp_no. :/

Comment: @user3705541 - just trust me.  try it.  if you have issues or questions, post another comment.  you shouldn't have any rows in your timesheet table where `emp_no` is null.  in fact, if you did, this approach would not work.  we would have to add a line to the join's `on` clause if it did.

Comment: I posted another problem there (I'm sorry I somehow don't know how to use stackoverflow properly)

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer!!

```
SELECT dtt.stmpdate, intime
FROM @datetemp dtt left join 
(
    SELECT stmpdate, intime
    FROM v_dayTimesheet 
    WHERE (emp_no = '001234567') 
) as vdayTimesheet
 on sparedate.stmpdate=vdayTimesheet.stampdate
ORDER BY stmpdate
```

this is what I want, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

SQL Query:
**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1511f/6)**

```
SELECT t2.dt,
       isnull(t1.intime, '') intime
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(day,number,'2014-10-01') dt
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE Type = 'P' 
    AND DATEADD(day,number,'2014-10-01') >= '2014-10-01'
    AND DATEADD(day,number,'2014-10-01') < '2014-11-01'
 ) t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.stmpdate = t2.dt
```

Result:

```
|                             DT |   INTIME |
|--------------------------------|----------|
| October, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 03 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 04 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 05 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 06 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 07 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 08 2014 00:00:00+0000 | 08:04:43 |
| October, 09 2014 00:00:00+0000 | 07:57:13 |
| October, 10 2014 00:00:00+0000 | 07:57:14 |
| October, 11 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 12 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 13 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 15 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 16 2014 00:00:00+0000 | 07:79:56 |
| October, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000 | 07:45:56 |
| October, 18 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 19 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 20 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 21 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 22 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 23 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 24 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 25 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 26 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 27 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 28 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 29 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 30 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
| October, 31 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          |
```